Example of an abelian sheaf satisfying a certain condition
Consider a site $(\sf C,\tau)$, an abelian sheaf $F$ on it and an object $U$ in $\sf C$. We say that $F$ has the property ($*$) with respect to a covering $\mathcal U:=\{U_i\to U\}_{i\in I}$ if it is true that: for any $r\ge 0$ and any choice of $i_0,\dots , i_r\in I$, it holds for $q\gt 0$ that $H^q(U_0\times_U\cdots\times_UU_r,F)=0$.
I'm thinking of an example of a sheaf satisfying the property ($*$) with respect to any covering of $U$.
The only reasonable assumption that came to my mind is that $H^q(F,U)=0$ for $q\gt 0$; however I couldn't prove that this assumption yields $(*)$ with respect to any covering of $U$, and I'm instead quite convinced that it is not even true.
Do you know any example of such a sheaf $F$? Or even some conditions involving $F$ and $U$ that imply  $(*)$ with respect to any covering of $U$? Thanks for any suggestion

Yes, $F = 0$. :)
